# Store Push Notification Messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have recently implemented a push notification feature in my app. It works very well. Two users could send message to each other via push notification.

However, I wonder how this push notification messages could be captured (stored) in the app, like a chatting app.

Comment: The delivery of notifications isn't guaranteed so they should serve as notification that there is a new message but they can't be the only store of the message. Typically you would store the messages on a server where the clients can retrieve the messages as required.